# AngularJS does not update view after $resouce.query

Tags: angularjs

I'm fetching data from backend using $resource.query. It's working. But after I got the response, the view doesn't change. It works when it's not inside a function.

this is my service

```
app.factory('myService', function ($q, $resource, $http) {
  var service = {};
service .pesquisar = function (param1, param2) {
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
  $resource(urlWebService + '/API/', null).query({
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
  }, function (dados) {
    resolve(dados);
  }, function (erro) {
    reject(erro);
  });
});
};
return service ;
});
```

this is my controller

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'myService',
 function ($scope, $resource, myService) {

//this call update the view
myService.fetchData('1234', '111111')
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data
  })
  .catch(function (erro) {
    console.log(erro);
  });

//this is called in a button click and doesn't change the view
$scope.getData = function () {
  myService.fetchData('1234', '111111')
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data
    })
    .catch(function (erro) {
      console.log(erro);
    });
}
}]);
```

and this is my view

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Field</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
        <td>{{d.field}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getData`() is invoked, you're appending the result to a variable `teste` that is not defined, instead of the `$scope`

```
$scope.getData = function () {
  myService.fetchData('1234', '111111')
    .then(function (data) {
      //teste.data = data 
        $scope.data = data; //will bind the result to the view
    })
    .catch(function (erro) {
      console.log(erro);
    });
}
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I did what you said and still doesn't work.. I don't think this should be so hard, I think I'm probably missing something...

Comment: try adding the whole code, in particular the part where you actually call getData()

Comment: I'm using ui-router with nested views, I got a button with ng-click calling getData() in one view and the ng-repeat in another view. I thought nested views shared the same controller but after placing the button on the same view I realize that they don't... Thank you though, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your second non working version equals `$scope.getData` to a function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Is there something it should return? I'm kinda new to this approach so I might be doing it wrong

Comment: Well, I suppose you need the response you got from the request, so the second one is not the way you are doing this. Because a function assignment of this kind is used when you bind it to an event. You need a resolved promise, so your first approach is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a promise is stored at "data" of your result variable so change your view to

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data.data">
```

Or your controller to

```
$scope.data = data.data;
```